# How can I merge dataframes of unequal length but known chunk length?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a model where individuals can die and reproduce. I record information from the model at set intervals. I know the identity of the individuals and the iteration number I sampled from:

```
df1<-data.frame(
who= c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,3,5),
iteration = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
)
df1
```

But each of the individuals has a list of numbers associated with it that I want to track. Because each individual has more than one number associated with it, I get two data frames of unequal sample size.

```
df2 <- data.frame(values=c(1,1, # id = 1
                           1,2, # id = 2
                           2,1, # id = 3
                           0,0, # id = 4
                           1,1, # id = 1
                           1,2, # id = 2
                           2,1, # id = 3
                           2,1, # id = 3
                           0,0)) # id = 5
df2
```

I want to bind them so the 'who' variable is matched up with its value. I did the following to split the values up into the right sized chunks but now I'm stuck.

```
df3 <- split(df2$values, ceiling(seq_along(df2$values)/2))
```

I should get something out that looks like this:

```
who iteration value1 value2
1      1      1       1
2      1      1       2
3      1      2       1
4      1      0       0
1      2      1       1
2      2      1       2
3      2      2       1
3      3      2       1  
5      3      0       0
```

Comment: Do you need `cbind(df1, split(df2$values, (seq_along(df2$values)-1) %% 2 +1))`

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain what the code is doing? How would I extend this where the individuals have > 2 values associated with them?

Comment: `lst <- split(df2$values, (seq_along(df2$values)-1) %% 2 +1); do.call(cbind, lapply(lst, "length<-", max(lengths(lst)))))`

Comment: That works, I just had to change the '2' to the number number of interest and delete an extra bracket at the end. Put it down as a full answer and I can mark it as a solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we `split` the 'values' column based on a grouping index created with `%%` into a `list` of `vector`s, then make the `list` element pad with `NA` at the end (in case if there are less number of elements) by assigning the `length<-` to the maximum `length` of `list` element

```
lst <- split(df2$values, (seq_along(df2$values)-1) %% 2 +1)
m1 <- do.call(cbind, lapply(lst, "length<-", max(lengths(lst))))
cbind(df1, m1)
```